# Add Librato Annotation on Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, librato

Is there an easy way to add a post-deploy command to a Heroku push/deploy which will add a corresponding annotation to Librato? (I'm using Rails if it makes a difference)

I'm currently looking at doing so by combining *[Heroku HTTP POST hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#http-post-hook)* with Librato *[HTTP annotations API](http://support.metrics.librato.com/knowledgebase/articles/122410-adding-annotations-to-graphs)* but it's not clear how to add parameter to Heroku's http hooks and Librato seems to need basic auth, can you do this using Heroku's hooks?

Am I on the right track, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku docs on Librato mentions [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/librato#annotations):

> Being able to correlate regressions with code deployments is immensely helpful, so we’re also tracking your Heroku app releases as Librato annotations. Release annotations have been added to all Instruments on the Overview dashboard. Paid accounts can add them to any Instrument using the releases annotation name.

I'm using the Librato add-on in Heroku and it indeed shows my deployments in the *Instruments section*, right out of the box. For example in the *HTTP Status Codes* instrument, it shows the *releases* annotations. You can also add it to your own instrument, just search for 'releases'.

See also the Librato [blog post](http://blog.librato.com/posts/heroku-status-codes-and-release-annotations) and the Librato [annotation gem](https://github.com/librato/librato-annotate).